# In GCP IAM admin, how do you activate the recommendation on some accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

In Google Cloud Platform's IAM section, there's a pretty handy tool that shows "Over granted permissions" in a column.

[image: Over granted permissions screenshot]

Some of those have a yellow lightbulb that can be clicked through to apply the recommendations.

Some are greyed out, and even though it sometimes lists the recommendations, it's completely turned out.

How do you enable those greyed out lightbulbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Recommendation not available  icon indicates that there are no recommended changes to the role. To find out why, hold the pointer over the icon.

[Reviewing and applying recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/recommender-managing)

Comment: Why is it showing two different numbers then? If i've got 1470/1478 over granted permissions, that seem like a legit recommendation to have

Comment: The only feedback I get from GCP is "No recommendation available. There are no other curated roles which optimize permission usage."

Comment: For instance I've got two service accounts, both set as Editor role. One gives me 1474/1478 with lightbulb on and one 1470/1478 with lightbulb off.

Comment: Oh, no I get it now. In the recommendation popup it is using a particular specific role recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for letting me think out loud through it :D